# How to select and loop through only items that meet certain conditions in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to loop through an array with a comparison operator being applied.

So, whereas this code:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 

foreach($arr as $key) 
{ 
    echo $key;
}
```

will `echo` "123456789," I want a code that could only list numbers greater than 5, or less than 5, etc. (So it would output 6789 or 1234.)

Note: I'm nearly sure there is a way to do this, and it is relatively simple, but I can't find a way to do it, and there appears to be no question asking this on stackoverflow. I have looked, but as my title shows, I'm not sure how to succinctly state this for googleing. Thank you.

Note: I had considered using an external condition check, but I guessed if there was a php function specifically for this, it would be more efficient.

UPDATE: array_filter was suggested, so I ran the following benchmark, to test whether the traditional or built-in approach was better here:

```
$arr=array(); 
for($x=1;$x<10001;$x++){
    $arr[]=$x;
}

$a1 = microtime();
foreach($arr as $key) {
    if ($key > 5000) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
$a2 = microtime();
$a3 = microtime();
$greater = array_filter($arr, function ($key) {
    return $key > 5000;
});

foreach($greater as $key) {
    echo $key;
}
$a4 = microtime();

$firsttest=$a2-$a1;
$secondtest=$a4-$a3;
echo '<br>'.$firsttest.'<br>'.$secondtest;
```

The second test took about twice to three times as long consistently, meaning using foreach and then using an if condition is far more efficient than using array_filter and then using a foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a condition around the echo.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 

foreach($arr as $key) {
    if ($key > 5) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Or use a ternary operator, echoing an empty string if it's not greater than five.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 

foreach($arr as $key) {
    echo $key > 5 ? $key : '';
}
```

And then there's [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which would allow you to extract all the `values > 5` and put them in their own array. It's useful if you need to keep those values around for later.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$greater = array_filter($arr, function($key) {
    return $key > 5;
});

foreach($greater as $key) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was originally doing, but I thought PHP might have a function built in to do this, which would be more effective, as there would be less iterations of the code.

Comment: Check my update. I'm going to leave the question open for a day or two to see if anyone comes with a better method. If not, I'll select your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 

foreach($arr as $key) 
{ 
  if($key > 5)
     echo $key;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was originally doing, but I thought PHP might have a function built in to do this, which would be more effective, as there would be less iterations of the code.